# What is the best way to refactor this generic method to satisfy SonarQube S4018

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sonarqube

SonarQube rule S4018 requires generic methods to provide the generic type as a parameter.

For example, this would be illegal because T is not passed in as a method parameter:

```
public T DoStuff<T>(string json)
{
    return someResult.ToObject<T>();
}

// call the method
var result = myClass.DoStuff<SomeObject>("some json");
```

This is the violation text: "Refactor this method to have parameters matching all the type parameters"

This is a link to the rule documentation: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=csharpsquid%3AS4018&rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS4018

Is there a straight-forward way to make this valid that I'm just not aware of? Is this rule even valid? The examples in the documentation only use void-type methods whereas I want a generic return type.

Comment: The rule is reasonable the way they define it. But the rule also should consider the return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea about this system, but it seems to complain about T not appearing in the Parameter list. I am unsure that is a legitimate warning. The only `List<T>` functions that use T as arguments are the Add ones. Everything else works perfectly fine with T being only used for the return type - or even nowhere at all.

If the existing generic classes written by people with decades of experience violate the rules, it is propably a stupid rule. If you really need to follow this rule, you could use a ref or out parameter instead of creating your own instance and returning, I guess?